# Rails create hash from loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, hash

I am trying to create a hash objects in my loop but I am getting error when I am tying to add one more object inside loop.

MY code is very simple:

```
 hash_data = b.map do |el| 
        { y: el[compare], label: "rain_fall_type1" }
        { y: el[rain_fall_type], label: compare }
end
```

This code gives me this result:

```
    [
    {
    y: 45.34,
    label: "Land_Area"
    },
    {
    y: 45.23,
    label: "Land_Area"
    }
]
```

When I am adding comma like this:

```
  hash_data = b.map do |el| 
        { y: el[compare], label: "rain_fall_type1" },
        { y: el[rain_fall_type], label: "Land_Area" }
end
```

I am getting  syntax error I want this type of result:

```
      [
    {
    y: 45.34,
    label: "rain_fall_type1"
    },
    {
    y: 46.23,
    label: "Land_Area"
    }
]
```

How can I generate result like this.

Comment: both result looks same to me, also of course it will give you syntax error

Comment: No in first result I am just getting  second object

Comment: Can you provide a sample data for `b`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nwoow/a1d0604002d8e00132d83541305f4dd9 This is the data

Comment: what is compare, and rain_fall_type?

Comment: Given your sample data, what's the expected result? (`compare` and `rain_fall_type` are not keys in sample data)

Comment: Geographical_Area and forest

Comment: This is returning just Geographical_Area `hash_data = b.map { |el| { y: el[:Geographical_Area]} }`. But better you show the expected results  editing your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash_data = b.map do |el| 
  { y: el[compare], label: "rain_fall_type1" }
  { y: el[rain_fall_type], label: compare }
end
```

This map block does not result in two hashes. It contains two different statements. The first creates a hash and throws it away. The second creates a hash which is returned from the map block since it's the last expression. The first statement does nothing.

If you want to return multiple hashes from a map block, or anything, you have to wrap them in another object like an array.

```
hash_data = b.map do |el| 
  [
    { y: el[compare], label: "rain_fall_type1" },
    { y: el[rain_fall_type], label: compare }
  ]
end
```

Comment: I know that but I don't want them inside array.

Comment: @user2480754 In that case, call [`.flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

Answer (score 0):

you can get your expected result with

```
hash_data = orders.map do |el|
  [{ y: el[compare], label: "rain_fall_type1" }, { y: el[rain_fall_type], label: "Land_Area" }]
end
hash_data.flatten
```

and if you want them in the pair of two

```
hash_data.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a
```